# return chartdirector image from sub object

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, charts

Hello i was trying to create a chart using `chartdirector` and vb.net 
what i exactly trying to do is create a `sub` that returns an image as object class and then append what ever return from the `sub` to image tag in my page

Here is what i have done so far :

```
   Private Sub createChart(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
    _System.EventArgs)
    Dim cd As Integer = CreateObject("ChartDirector.API")
    Dim chart As XYChart = New XYChart(700, 170)
    Dim values As Double() = {25, 18, 15, 12, 8, 30, 35}
    Dim labels As String() = {"Labor", "Licenses", "Taxes", "Legal", 
    "Insurance", "Facilities", "Production"}
    chart.setPlotArea(30, 20, 200, 200)
    chart.addBarLayer(values)
    chart.xAxis().setLabels(labels)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/png"
    Dim mina As BinaryWriter = chart.makeChart2()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End()

End Sub
```

the code break at this line

```
 Dim mina As BinaryWriter = chart.makeChart2()
```

with the following error `Argument not specified for parameter format of public overridable function makechart2(format as integer ) As Byte()`

any idea how to fix this will be great 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error, `makeChart2` requires an integer parameter, and it also looks like it returns an array of `Byte`, not a `BinaryWriter`.

I'm not familiar with `chartdirector`, so I don't know if there is an alternative, or if you'll have to refactor your code, but if it is the latter, you'll need to new up a `BinaryWriter`, and `Write` the return value from `makeChart2` to it.